# One to One mapping get null value Spring boot JPA Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented one to one relationship and when I try to insert value it gives an below  exception.

I've tried many stackoverflow answers but no luck yet. I can't figure out what went to wrong.

Exception :

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null
> property references a null or transient value
>
> not-null property references a null or transient value

FullPack Entity

```
@Entity(name = "FullPack")
@Table(name = "fullpack")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class FullPack {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fullpack_id")
    int fullPackId;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String sequence;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String channelRestriction;


    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String actNotAllowed;


    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String packCompose;

}
```

Pack Sequence Entity

```
@Entity
public class PackSequence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int packSequenceId;

    int sequenceId;

    int packId;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fullpack_packsequence_id", referencedColumnName = "fullpack_id", nullable = false)
    private FullPack fullPack;
}
```

Insert record to FullPack table(intentionally insert null values for JSON fields)

```
{
    "fullPackId": 1,
    "sequence": null,
    "channelRestriction": null,
    "actNotAllowed": null,
    "packCompose": null
}
```

Insert record to PackSequence table

Updated from Chun's answer but same issue exists

```
  {
        "sequenceId":1,
        "packId":2,
        "fullpack" : {
            "fullpack_id":1
        }
  }
```

Mysql Table Structure

FullPack Table

[image]

PackSequence Table
[image]

Comment: Could you please show how you insert value.

Comment: @SternK : I've updated question and added Postman calls please refer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is likely to do with the Json transformation from Postman to PackSequence and FullPack objects has issued

you will need to use JsonProperty to help remapping the field name.

I have to modify your PackSequence and FullPack object as following

```java
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PackSequence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int packSequenceId;

    int sequenceId;

    int packId;


    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "fullpack_packsequence_id", referencedColumnName = "fullpack_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("fullpack")
    private FullPack fullPack;

    // omit getter and setter
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "FullPack")
@Table(name = "fullpack")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FullPack
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fullpack_id")
    @JsonProperty("fullpack_id")
    int fullPackId;

    private String sequence;
    private String channelRestriction;
    private String actNotAllowed;
    private String packCompose;

    // omit getter and setter
}
```

assuming you insert the object from JSON Payload via RestController, etc.

the PackSequence json object should look like this

```
{
    "sequenceId":1,
    "packId":2,
    "fullpack" : {
        "fullpack_id":1
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue :( no luck

Comment: This is the correct way of sending Postman JSON request and I will update this to my question. but still I get same exception.